# Raspberry PI wifi dongle not recognised

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi2

I use **the original Raspberry WiFi dongle** on a Raspberry Pi 2. I changed `interface` file in `etc/network` and the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, addding the SSID and the psk password for my wifi connection. And yet, I am not able to connect to my wifi network. What is even stranger is that in the GUI it seems that the Rasberry doesn't recognise the wifi dongle. When I left-click on the network icon, it says `No wireless interfaces found`.
Do you have any suggestions that may help me solve this issue?
Here are the last lines of the `dmesg` command

```
[20108.919617] usb 1-1.2: Product: Remote Download Wireless Adapter
[20108.919633] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Broadcom
[20108.919650] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[20109.170317] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Apr  3 2014 04:43:32 version 6.10.198.66 (r467479) FWID 01-32bd010e
[20109.190470] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[20109.278344] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
[20109.278371] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
```

Here is what the `ifconfig wlan0`  command gives:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:ee:b4:87:2d:09  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b6ee:b4ff:fe87:2d09/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3500 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1431948 (1.3 MiB)  TX bytes:11710 (11.4 KiB)
```